# HTML background image for title

Tags: html, css, image, background, background-image

I was looking at ways to include a title in a page and I have come across this website: (see image below) which does exactly what I want but I can't figure out how to accomplish it. The trouble I have is in only having a single title image at the top without it repeating through to the bottom. I have used the css background-image:url(image) on the main div but the repeating image problem is present. Any help or insight on this matter will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I need the rest of the background to repeat until the end. I think having the rest of the background be a separate image may be part of the solution but I don't know if a title image div can be forced to the same layer. Again any insight is valuable as I am new to HTML and CSS. Also this is the best example website I can find, if you are offended please edit with a better example. Thank You!

[image]

Comment: [background-repeat:no-repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat)

Comment: Better you study the basics of CSS and HTML from any good online tutorial. For this context this link may help you [Link-CSS Background property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp)

Comment: Thank You Prasanth! I am trying to do the same thing that is in your link's example, only with an image instead of a color. Does it work the same way?

Comment: @PrasanthKC, your answer led me to find this website http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/ which provided working examples of how to do what I need. Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it and give you credit. I will post an answer later today if you do not. Thanks again!

Comment: @JaaMills happy to hear that my comment helped you. my comment has been posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it done using the below CSS,

```
#elemId
{
 background: #00ff00 url('testimage.jpg') no-repeat top left;
}
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

This is the css trick to NOT repeat a background image.

If you didn't know this already, how the hell could you make it to this website ?

from you link

```
body {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  background: url("/marines-theme/images/layout/body-background.jpg") repeat-x scroll left 23px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 980px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#overview-wrap {
  background: url("/image/image_gallery?uuid=a394504c-a638-449e-bb56-b517cfe7d3ee&groupId=10162&t=1349957392552") no-repeat scroll center top #000000;
}
```

Those are nested markups like so :

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="overview-wrap"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

That's about it.

ps. i added a screenshot of what you want to show. Can you remove the (now useless) link?

Comment: I may need to rephrase my question... I don't want the TITLE IMAGE to repeat. The rest of the background (which is a solid black color in the example website but an actual image in mine) should repeat until the page ends. Yes I knew that..... I wouldn't post a question that I haven't thought about. I am still very new at HTML though so more insight into background options or div options would be helpful.

Comment: That website was actually made by the united states marine corps, but its the best example I can find. The question has been edited for clarity.